# Bigquery session number not working as on boilerplate example

Tags: google-bigquery

I am following this example:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/bigquery/advanced-queries#user_pseudo_id

I have made three main changes to the above, the first is to change the timezone,
the second is to pass my own list of user_pseudo_id (which comes from the "removed" cte), the third is to change the duration to last 30 days instead of 4 (by using BETWEEN GetDateSuffix(-30). And ofcourse I changed my data table!

Here is my modified version of the code:

```
with removed as (

SELECT distinct user_pseudo_id as removed_users
from `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
where event_name = "app_remove"

and

DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE from TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)), DAY) 
between DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
and
DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
 
)
,
session_counts as

(
-- Get the latest ga_session_id and ga_session_number for specific users during last 4 days.

-- Replace timezone. List at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones.

DECLARE REPORTING_TIMEZONE STRING DEFAULT 'Asia/Karachi';

-- Replace list of user_pseudo_id's with ones you want to query.
DECLARE USER_PSEUDO_ID_LIST ARRAY<STRING> DEFAULT
  select * from removed;

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetParamValue(params ANY TYPE, target_key STRING)
AS (
  (SELECT `value` FROM UNNEST(params) WHERE key = target_key LIMIT 1)
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetDateSuffix(date_shift INT64, timezone STRING)
AS (
  (SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(timezone), INTERVAL date_shift DAY)))
);

SELECT DISTINCT
  user_pseudo_id,
  FIRST_VALUE(GetParamValue(event_params, 'ga_session_id').int_value)
    OVER (UserWindow) AS ga_session_id,
  FIRST_VALUE(GetParamValue(event_params, 'ga_session_number').int_value)
    OVER (UserWindow) AS ga_session_number
FROM
  -- Replace table name.
  `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
WHERE
  user_pseudo_id IN UNNEST(USER_PSEUDO_ID_LIST)
  AND RIGHT(_TABLE_SUFFIX, 8)
    BETWEEN GetDateSuffix(-30, REPORTING_TIMEZONE)
    AND GetDateSuffix(0, REPORTING_TIMEZONE)
WINDOW UserWindow AS (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY event_timestamp DESC))

select * from session_counts
```

I am facing the following error:

```
Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT or keyword WITH but got keyword DECLARE at [23:1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a little peek with your code and the error. It appears that you cannot use declare and create variables within the CTE. It is advised to declare these variables outside a CTE. I believe such definitions are better explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16#cte_query_definition).